# Leaderboard from mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How could I add a number starting from 1 to show the leader by total games in this script?

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT gamertag, tgames FROM leader ORDER BY tgames DESC");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "number? ".$row['gamertag']." ".$row['tgames']."<br>\n";
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply add a variable that increases each time.

```
  <?php

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT gamertag, tgames FROM leader ORDER BY tgames DESC");

  $index = 1;
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $index++ . " " . $row['gamertag'] . " " . $row['tgames'] . "<br>\n";
  }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(...)
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $i . " " .$row['gamertag']." ".$row['tgames']."<br>\n";
    $i++;
}
```